# Save picture to a variety of file formats

Tags: delphi, canvas, save, delphi-2007, image

I have a routine `procedure DrawStuff(ACanvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRect)` that draws something to a specified rectangle on a TCanvas. At the moment I call `DrawStuff` with a PaintBox's canvas. Now I'm adding a `Save as` option, in which the user shall be able to select from a variety of file formats (bmp, wmf, jpg, ... - preferrably as many TGraphic descendants as possible) to save the results of `DrawStuff` to.

Drawing to a `TMetafile` and saving that as "bla.bmp" or `Assign`ing it to a `TPicture` doesn't work correctly - e.g. it produces files with extension ".bmp" that **aren't** bitmaps. Right now I can't figure a solution that doesn't involve special-casing every single file format:

- bmp - Use `TBitmap.Canvas`.
- wmf/emf: Use `TMetafileCanvas`.
- etc. etc.

Do you know have any ideas for me?

Comment: It is very easy to make a 'uniform' routine to save BMP, PNG, GIF, JPG, etc., but it is much harder to do it if it is also to include WMF or EMF, since the latter are *vector image* formats, while the former are *raster image* formats. Unless, of course, you choose to save the image as a raster bitmap embedded in your EMF/WMF, but in such a case it is plain stupid to use the EMF/WMF format at all...

Comment: Special-casing wmf/emf would be OK. Can you give me pointers to the uniform routine you mention?

Comment: PS: I thought drawing to a metafile and then `Assign`ing it to a `TPicture` might work as it seems to be something like a collection of recorded GDI calls.

Comment: Yes, it isn't really *much*  harder in practice, as I wrote above, if you know in advance that you should save all these operations.

Comment: Special casing is the right solution. Why don't you want to do that? A PNG is different from a JPG is different from a WMF. How would you be able to save each of them without some variation?

Comment: @David: I hoped to leverage Delphi's TPicture/TGraphic mechanism to save me some work.

Comment: How would it save you work? Your code to create all the images has to be different. Why would would want to stuff them into a TPicture and then save? Just save it straight away, cut out a step and get good quality results. I'm sorry I misunderstood the question but it really blindsided me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess a "dumb" conversion would probably as simple as this :

```
type
  TGraphicTypeEnum = (gteBMP, gteJPG, gteTIF, gtePNG);

procedure SaveGraphicAs(AGraphic : TGraphic; AGraphicType : TGraphicTypeEnum; AFileName : String);
var vGraphicClass : TGraphicClass;
    vTargetGraphic : TGraphic;
    vBmp : TBitmap;
begin

  case AGraphicType of
    gteBMP : vGraphicClass := TBitmap;
    gtejpg : vGraphicClass := TJPEGImage;
    gtetif : vGraphicClass := TWICImage;
    gtepng : vGraphicClass := TPngImage;
  else
    // EXIT; or raise...
  end;
  if aGraphic is vGraphicClass then //As suggested by Rob Kennedy
    AGraphic.SaveToFile(AFileName)
  else
  begin
    vBmp := nil;
    vTargetGraphic := vGraphicClass.Create;
    try
      vBmp := TBitmap.Create;
      vBmp.Assign(AGraphic);
      vTargetGraphic.Assign(vBmp);
      vTargetGraphic.SaveToFile(aFileName);
    finally
      vTargetGraphic.Free;
      vBmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Assigning to a TPicture didn't work, as when you assign to a TPicture, TPicture will convert the graphic to the class you are assigning from.

Note that in my example, there is 2 layers of conversion as the original image is converted to bitmap before being converted to the final format. There can be quite a bit of loss of information in the process. Most (all?) graphic type know how to convert to and from TBitmap, but TJPEGImage has no idea how to convert to TPngImage and vice versa.

More efficient conversion method can be developed that keeps transparency and other effects specific to a file format, but that is beyong my knowledge. But depending on your needs, that might be sufficient.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to check `if AGraphic is vGraphicClass` and skip the bitmap conversion if it's true. Otherwise, you'll lose image quality even when saving a JPEG as a JPEG.

Comment: Or skip calling the function SaveGraphicAs at all and just call AGraphic.SaveToFile. There is quite a few other issues that could crop out. A 3rd party could register their own PNG class (DevExpress does that). So you would end up with `TdxPNGImage is TPNGImage` (Which would be false). It is sadly not possible at the moment to get the currently registered class for a given extension (QC57402 requested on 2008-01-24... Still open). It's probably easier for the caller to figure out if the graphic is already in the proper format. But yeah, I guess it wouldn't hurt to make that optimisation.

Comment: "[dcc32 Warning] main.pas(101): W1036 Variable 'vGraphicClass' might not have been initialized" How to solve this?